# Swift performance: getting rid of ContiguousArrayStorage deinit

Tags: swift

I'm trying to optimize some loop in Swift.

I have this class,

```
class SphericalHarmonics {
    /** SphericalHarmonics Samples */
    struct SHSample {
        var sph:    Spherical
        var vec:    Vector3
        var coeff:  [Double]
    }

    let numBands    : UInt
    let numCoeffs   : UInt
    let numSamples  : UInt
    var samples     : [SHSample]
    var coeffs      : [Vector3]
```

and in init I initialize all the matrices and then loop over 10000 samples accessing those matrices again.

```
    let coefficients = [Double](count: Int(numCoeffs), repeatedValue: 0)
    let emptySample = SHSample(sph: Spherical(), vec: Vector3(), coeff: coefficients)
    samples = [SHSample](count: Int(self.numSamples), repeatedValue: emptySample)
    coeffs = [Vector3](count: Int(numCoeffs), repeatedValue: Vector3())
    // ...
    var i = 0 // array index
    for a in 0..<numSamplesSqrt {
        for b in 0..<numSamplesSqrt {
            // ...
            samples[i].sph = Spherical(r: 1.0, θ: Float(θ), φ: Float(φ))
            // convert spherical coords to unit vector
            samples[i].vec = samples[i].sph.ToVector3()
            // precompute all SH coefficients for this sample
            for l in 0..<Int(numBands) {
                for m in -l...l {
                    let ci = l * (l+1) + m // coefficient index
                    samples[i].coeff[ci] = SH(l: l,m: m,θ: θ,φ: φ)
                }
            }
            ++i
```

The first mistake here was reading from samples[i]. A profiling session revealed that Swift.Array._copyBuffer of SHSample was taking 2.2 sec, and ContiguousArrayStorage._deallocating_deinit was taking 2 sec. I did this simple change and saved 4 seconds :)

```
            let sph = Spherical(r: 1.0, θ: Float(θ), φ: Float(φ))
            samples[i].sph = sph
            // convert spherical coords to unit vector
            samples[i].vec = sph.ToVector3()
```

However, there are still 200ms of ContiguousArrayStorage._deallocating_deinit that come from the last inner loop where I'm accessing samples[i].coeff[ci]. I don't really understand why deinit needs to be called, since the arrays are already created and I'm just modifying their data.

Any idea why?

(If you want to see the full code, it's here: https://github.com/endavid/Harmonikr/blob/master/Harmonikr/math/SphericalHarmonics.swift )